# Is it possible to change the Django.Form normalization type?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Form` class in a Django project with a few `MultipleChoiceFields` which I feed it choices of `(int, str)`. When the form performs the data cleanup on the input values of the `MultipleChoiceFields`, the input values are of type int but to my surprise, when they get cleaned, the the django `to_python()` normalizes them to strings. Is there a way for me to specify what the normalization type should be for a `FormField`? Hopefully without having to create a child class and overwrite the original behavior?

Edit: Form example

```
class MyForm(forms.Form)
    owner = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label=gettext_lazy("Owners"),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs{"class":"form_multi_select"}),)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.choice_options = kwargs.pop("choice_options")
    
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         owners = self.choice_options.get("owner")
         self.fields["owners"].choices = owners.ungrouped() if owners else []
```

Comment: share your form logic/code

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant since it's a basic django Form behavior that I'm asking about but I added it :)

Comment: where are you passing your choices ? like list of choices while initialising forms ?